# Chrome Developer Tools does not show response body for HTTP 401 response

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Developer Tools does not show response body for HTTP 401 response. Can Chrome Developer Tools be configured to show response body for HTTP 401 response?

Comment: Are you making ajax calls? Do you have any error like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load..` in your console?

Comment: I can remember that I was making Ajax calls. I can't remember whether there are some `XMLHttpRequest cannot load..` errors.

Comment: I have the same issue. Normally servers send 401 when they want to use browsers native login form. Chrome open its native login form but does not show the 401 response in network tab.